# What do we currently know about the storyline of Harry Potter Magic Awakens?

Tags: harry-potter

Today, there was huge online buzz about this new video game called "Harry Potter: Magic Awakens".

What do we currently know about this game's storyline and when does it take place?

Will the game have any impact on canon?

Comment: FIXED LINK: Still up: https://twitter.com/mystikgunn/status/1047250063427231744?s=21

Answer (score 9):

## It’s rumored to be set in the 19th century - unclear if it’ll be canon.

From information that was possibly leaked about the game, it’s rumored to be set in the 19th century, and will center around the main character who the player will design. It’s unclear if the game is supposed to be considered canon, if things shown in it are intended to be considered canon hasn’t been mentioned. However, one change from canon that’s already noticeable in the possible description for it is that the main character is accepted into Hogwarts late. There’s never been any mention of a student who shows magic only after eleven years old.

> Set in the 19th Century (1800’s) Wizarding World, this 3rd person open-world action RPG game centers around your character with unique abilities who has earned a late acceptance to Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry.
>
> You are a newly arrived 5th-year student to Hogwarts that demonstrates a latent gift for magic with a unique ability to track and identify remnants of a pottant ancient power. Upon arrival, strange events begin to materialize In the Forbidden Forrest and trouble begins o brew within the castle walls. Together with Professor Elezar Fig, you embark on a journey through both familiar and never before seen locations to bring to light the truth behind these mysterious occurrences.
>
> On your quest you will craft potions, master new spells, and discover fantastical beasts. You will battle Dark Wizards, Goblins, and other supernatural enemies and uncover the truth about your destiny – the Fate of the Wizarding World lies in your hands.
>
> FEATURES
>
> - Journey to Hogwarts to become one of 8 different Wizard types.
> - Experience Hogwarts, make new friends, uncover new secrets, and change the fate of the Wizarding world.
> - Experience a new magic system that creates countless possibilities to master magic.
> - Freely explore the Wizarding World for the first time., Choose your house and friends at Hogwarts, and decide to pursue a path of good or evil.
> - Create your own witch or wizard, and experience an all new story separate from the books or films. 
>   <sub><sup>*[- Harry Potter Open World Action RPG Leaked with Stunning Gameplay Showcase (WCC Tech)](https://wccftech.com/harry-potter-open-world-rpg-leaked/)*</sup></sub>

It’s uncertain that this is even an accurate description of the game, so it’s not possible yet to say for sure when the game will be set, or very much else about it, while so much is still unclear. A BBC reporter has said, though, that the footage is indeed from a real game.

> Footage of an unannounced “Harry Potter” role-playing game supposedly leaked online on Tuesday. Now, a BBC journalist says the game is real and it has a name — “Harry Potter: Magic Awakened.”
>
> “Am told this is from a yet to be announced RPG currently titled ‘Harry Potter: Magic Awakened,’ although other titles including ‘Magic Forever’ are also in the mix,” BBC entertainment correspondent Lizo Mzimba tweeted to Variety on Tuesday. “Other ‘Potter’ games are also thought to be on the way @TomPhillipsEG @ComicBook #HarryPotterMagicAwakened #HarryPotter.” 
> <sub><sup>*[- Leaked ‘Harry Potter’ RPG Is Reportedly Real, Called ‘Magic Awakened’ (Variety)](https://variety.com/2018/gaming/news/leaked-harry-potter-rpg-magic-awakened-1202966926/)*</sup></sub>

However, though he says the game does exist, he doesn’t say anything comfirming whether the information posted about the game’s plot and setting is authentic.

Comment: "Master New Spells" That implies there will be new spells added to canon(?)...

Comment: New student in the 5th year? Sounds like a nighmare, having to catch up on so much knowledge so fast...

Comment: im banking on this meaning he had to leave the other school or move country